# SQL tables with similar structure - best practices

Tags: sql, database, performance, schema, structure

Imagine that we have a website where users can read articles, view photos, watch videos, and many more. Every "item" may be commented, so that we need space to save that comments somewhere. Let's discuss storage possibilities for this case.

---

**Distributed solution**

We can obviously create separate tables for each "item", so that we have tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and then obviously `photo_comments`, `video_comments`, and so on. The advantages of this way are as follows:

- we can specify Foreign Key to every "item" table,
- database is divided into logical parts.
- there is no problem with export of such data.

Disadvantages:

- many tables
- probably hard to maintain (adding fields, etc.)

---

**Centralized solution**

On the other hand we can merge all those tables into two:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Table `comment_types` is a dictionary, it contains key-value pairs of commented item "type" and its name, for example :

```
1:Articles
2:Photos
3:Videos
```

Table `comments` stores usual data with additional `type` field.

Advantages:

- Maintenance (adding / removing fields),
- Adding new comment types "on the fly".

Disadvantages:

- Harder to migrate / export,
- Possible performance drop when querying large dataset.

---

**Discussion:**

- Which storage option will be better in terms of query performance (assume that dataset IS big enough for that to be the case),
- Again performance - will adding INDEX on `type` remove or drastically reduce that percormance drop?
- Which storage option will be better in terms of management and possible migration in the future (distributed will be better, of course, but let's see if centralized one isn't the one far away)

Comment: Well, what you propose is a simplified form of the Smith&Smith model. Nothing wrong with it, excellent performance on modern SQL implementations.

Comment: @wildplasser - What is the Smith&Smith model? First time I have heard of it. Can you link to it?

Comment: Never heard about `Smith&Smith`, can you share some links / elaborate a little bit more on the topic?

Comment: not sure if there is an 'answer' but my opinion is go with the second option. - yes indexes will help.

Comment: http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=smith%20%26%20smith%20data%20model&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.igi-global.com%2Fviewtitlesample.aspx%3Fid%3D51125&ei=wkCoTtarGYag-wbL4PXMDw&usg=AFQjCNFpBeWL0VB7vo1h0R7gX_nBxJ6bgg&cad=rja (PDF alert)

Comment: Lazy Badger, can you explain what errors I made?

Comment: http://svensky.free.fr/Cours/DDB/Smith%20-%20Data%20base%20Abstractions%20Aggregation%20and%20Generalization.pdf (PDF alert) this one is better. Hard to find, because publicated before the internet era.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure either of the disadvantages you list for option 2 are serious, data export is easily accomplished with a simple WHERE clause and I wouldn't worry about performance. Option 2 is properly normalised and in a modern relational database performance should be excellent (and can be tweaked further with appropriate indexes etc if necessary).

I would only consider the first option if I could prove that it was necessary for performance, scalability or other reasons - but it must be said that seems unlikely.

Comment: You've covered most points - thank you. For the disadvantages - I had to put something there so I thought of everything, even unlikely, to fill that part so that someone can prove me wrong. :)